# Half done do-release-upgrade -- now at grub rescue

Tags: grub2, do-release-upgrade

My computer is running single boot Ubuntu 12.04 server version.
I was trying to upgrade the release to 12.10 (following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/QuantalUpgrades)

After executing `sudo do-release-upgrade`, and agreed to proceed with the download, somehow I lost my video output (hdmi). Nothing was shown to vga output either.

I was able to ssh to my server but was not able to know what was going on with the release upgrade. I just waited long enough till dpkg no longer shows up on top, then I rebooted my server. (yeah, that was a dumb reboot )

Now I'm stuck at

```
error: file not found
grub rescue>
```

I can see my disk using

```
grub rescue> ls (hd0, msdos1)/
```

Comment: my goal is to upgrade to 13.10, 12.10 is an intermediate step. I chose upgrade as I do want to maintain what i have on there.

Comment: @Alvar 12.10 is not EOL. Still.

Answer (score -1):

These kinds of issues are notoriously hard to fix. Something went wrong with your grub, so what I can think of are three options:

1. Load in a Ubuntu Live CD and do a grub repair on that partition. One of the best tools for the job is [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).
2. Backup data and reformat hard drive.
3. [Sorta don't advice] Try to manually fix grub.

I would strongly suggest you go with the first one.

Comment: Thx. Trying out the 1st approach... Finger crossed

Comment: UPDATE: Tried out Boot Repair but had no luck with it. 
Then i played with grub rescue a bit and it seems that somehow i don't even have a grub dir under boot. I ended up with fresh installing 13.10.